# finding % of NULL values in a SQL table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the % of values in a whole table that is NULL using SQL.

However, we cannot refer to a specific column. As this query should be able to be run on any table without knowing beforehand how many columns we are referring to? Is this possible?

Possible logic avenue I thought of is maybe the following steps:

1. Count the number of columns
2. Use a loop to count NULL values in each column
3. Move the cursor to the next column once we reach last row (dont know if this is possible)
4. Keep doing this until the number of columns is met

I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: Pls tag database. Also share what you have done so far?

Comment: Totally possible. Just inform the database you want to run the SQL against (SQL Server? Oracle?) as the meta-tables of each database are different.

Comment: Many (most?) databases do have INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, i.e. the ANSI SQL way!

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I'm using an Exasol database.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname = 'dbo';
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'YourTable';

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000) = N'WITH cte (AllRows, NullRows) As (SELECT 0, 0 '

SELECT
    @Sql = @Sql + N'UNION ALL SELECT Count(*), ' + CASE
        WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN N'Count(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N')'
        ELSE N'0'
    END + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + N' '
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
And
    TABLE_NAME = @TableName
;

SET @Sql = @Sql + ') SELECT 100. * SUM(NullRows) / SUM(AllRows) FROM cte;'

EXEC(@Sql);
```